# Copy file to remote windows server in php

Tags: php, sql-server, html

How would I go about copying a file in PHP to a remote server? I would prefer to not use external libraries

Comment: What file transfer facilities does the remote server support? SMB, FTP, SCP, NFS?

Comment: Does it have to use a transfer service? Can't use php's copy

Comment: No, `copy()` will only work on the local file system, or filesystems attached to the local filesystem.

Comment: If I mapped a network drive would it work?

Comment: Yes, if your running script has permission to write to the mapped drive you can use copy with a destination of '\\your\network\path'.

Comment: @george: it'll work with anything that php's url handlers and streams system will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [FTP Function](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.ftp.php) to copy file from local to remote **:**

```
<?php
$connect = ftp_connect('111.111.111');  //connect to server

$login = ftp_login($connect, 'ftp_username', 'ftp_password'); 

if($login) 
{ 
    if(ftp_put($connect, '/home/user/john/tes.txt','tes.txt', FTP_BINARY)) 
    { 
        echo "Success";
    } 
} 

ftp_close($connect); 
?>
```